# Early multifunction laser printer with a fixed scanning head?

Tags: printer, identify-this-peripheral

I was working for a Hungarian magazine in the early 90s which had the most curious device: a laser printer which had a pass-through scanner on top, i.e. you laid down a page and it dragged it under a fixed head and that's how it scanned (see today's mobile scanners Fujitsu ScanSnap iX100 or the Epson DS-70 for examples, it basically had one of these bolted on top). It was a desktop model about the same with as an A4 sheet but very long. Does anyone have any idea what this could've been?

Comment: What is it exactly you're asking for?

Comment: @Raffzahn I think this is a hardware identification question: “what is the name of this printer?” or similar. Though it might just be “describe the technology”.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 exactly what I was wondering about. I started to write an answer about scan lines when realising that it not really irs, so I have absolutely no idea what he likes to know.

Comment: It is name of the printer. I mean, there couldn't have been many MFCs around that early.

Comment: *... the most curious device: ... a pass through scanner on top ie you laid down a page and it dragged it under a fixed head and that's how it scanned"* -- Doesn't sound *"curious"* at all.  That's how the typical low-cost scanner with a sheet feeder works.  The Brother MFCs that I have owned had/have a flat-bed scanner (and of course the head was motorized) as well as a document/sheet feeder.  So there was a short, wide window at the end of the scanner bed, under the feeder.  Such a scanner can also handle various paper sizes (i.e. lengths).

Comment: I do not think this was so common 1993-ish and the device was likely even older.